# dynamic call of null when running DataTable widget

Tags: flutter

i want to make a table that have dynamically column and row. i try to run it with custom class and list but it gets error "Dynamic call of null"

this is the error that i get.

[image]

this is my data table class

```
DataTable(
            dividerThickness: Cl.dp0,
            dataRowMaxHeight: Cl.dp40,
            dataRowMinHeight: Cl.dp8,
            headingRowHeight: Cl.dp40,
            headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                (states) => ClColors.secondary10),
            headingTextStyle: ClTypography.normal2SemiBold
                .copyWith(color: ClColors.primary20),
            dataTextStyle:
                ClTypography.normal2SemiBold.copyWith(color: ClColors.dark20),
            columns: widget.tableColumn!.map((element) {
              return DataColumn(label: Text(element));
            }).toList(),
            rows: widget.currencyList!.map((row) {
              return DataRow(
                cells: widget.tableColumn!.map((column) {
                  return DataCell(Text(row[column]!));
                }).toList(),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
```

and my main class

```
class Currency {
  String currencyName, buyingPrice, sellingPrice;
  Currency(
    this.currencyName,
    this.buyingPrice,
    this.sellingPrice,
  );
}

class _ExampleTableScreenState extends State<ExampleTableScreen> {
  List<Currency> currencyList = <Currency>[
    Currency('USDDDDDDDDDDDD', '14,398.00', '14,398.00'),
    Currency('SGD', '14,398.000000000000', '14,398.00'),
    Currency('AUD', '14,398.00', '14,398.0000000000'),
    Currency('CAD', '14,398.00', '14,398.00'),
    Currency('CHF', '14,398.00', '14,398.00'),
    Currency('CNY', '14,398.00', '14,398.00'),
  ];
  List<String> tableColumn = <String>['currency', 'buy', 'sell'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Table'),
        backgroundColor: ClColors.primary10,
      ),
      body: CloveTable(
        tableColumn: tableColumn,
        currencyList: currencyList,
      ),
    );
  }
```

what makes my widget is error? and help me please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got the error is you are trying to access `Currency.currencyName` with `Currency['currency']`.

Two mistakes you made:

1. you can not access object's property with `[]`
2. the property you want to access is `currencyName` instead of `curreny`

One possible fix is replace your currencyList with below list of map:

```
List<Map<String, String>> currencyList = [
  {
    "currency": "USDDDDDDDDDDDD",
    "buy": "14,398.00",
    "sell": "14,398.00",
  }
  // ...other data
]
```

Comment: i see. thanks for your answer. really appreciate it.